# RobolectricContext missing for gradle based project

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric

with v2.0 of robolectric and a gradle based project I am facing the problem of a missing RobolectricContext for the runner. It works with
testCompile group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'robolectric', version: '2.0-alpha-2'

and fails with 
testCompile group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'robolectric', version: '2.0'

I have the feeling that my problem is in my gradle build file, but I found no way to fix it yet:

```
apply plugin : 'java-robolectric'
apply plugin : 'idea'

// get 'java-robolectric' from Maven Central
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    // use version 2.0 for Robolectric 2.0
    classpath group: 'com.stanfy.android', name: 'gradle-plugin-java-robolectric', version: '2.0'
  }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
        }
    }
}

version = '0.9'

javarob {
    packageName = 'org.ligi.androidhelper'
}

test {
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include "**/*Test.class"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

test {
    afterTest { desc, result ->
        println "Executing test ${desc.name} [${desc.className}] with result: ${result.resultType}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir : 'libs', include : '*.jar')

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '1.8.0'

    compile group: 'com.google.android', name: 'android', version: '4.1.1.4'
    testCompile group: 'org.robolectric', name: 'robolectric', version: '2.0'
}
```

that is the error I get:

```
ligi@ligi-tp:~/git/AndroidHelper$ gradle test
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test
Executing test classMethod [org.ligi.androidhelper.test.CheckBoxHelperTest] with result: FAILURE

org.ligi.androidhelper.test.CheckBoxHelperTest > classMethod FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
Executing test classMethod [org.ligi.androidhelper.test.BitmapHelperTest] with result: FAILURE

org.ligi.androidhelper.test.BitmapHelperTest > classMethod FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException

2 tests completed, 2 failed
:test FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///home/ligi/git/AndroidHelper/build/reports/tests/index.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.723 secs
```

The full source is here:
https://github.com/ligi/AndroidHelper

Comment: RobolectricContext is not available in the source of Robolectric 2.0 any more. I'm currently looking for a good way to migrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a workaround is not to remove the Runner.java - because it always gets autogenerated by the robolectric gradle plugin with the faulty code ( usage of RobolectricContex )  then. The trick is to modify this file - even though you actually don't intend to make use of it - mine looks like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.robolectric.AndroidManifest;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;

/**                                                    
 * Use this runner instead of RobolectricTestRunner with @RunWith annotation.
 */
public class Runner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public Runner(final Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The class `RobolectricContext` is not required any more. Further it does not exist in Robolectric 2.0. You can simply override methods from within the `RobolectricTestRunner`.

For example, finding the `AndroidManifest.xml` can be achieved via:

```
@Override
protected AndroidManifest createAppManifest(FsFile manifestFile) {
  if (!manifestFile.exists()) {
    manifestFile = Fs.fileFromPath("pathToMy/AndroidManifest.xml");
  }
  return super.createAppManifest(manifestFile);
}
```

Comment: Or, even easier, use the @Config(manifest="MyFile.xml") annotation, or create a file called "org.robolectric.Config.properties". There should be little need to extend RobolectricTestRunner any longer.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I do not want to use a custom Runner - actually I am using the default one:

import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)

But the Runner.java gets generated with the failing code no matter what.